# Wrong encoding of name in mail notification

Tags: bug, email, survey-2019

I've got several notifications about SO Developer survey, each containing presumably my name in a wrong encoding.
[image: Mail screenshot]

Comment: Not that there's anything wrong with your old name but this new one looks way cooler.

Comment: It's your name written in the language of Mordor.

Comment: Just curious because I couldn't find any visible sources for your wrong encoded name, but is your "full name" on the bottom of [edit profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) using non-Latin characters (e.g. Cyrillic)?

Comment: I have a Google account linked to my profile and there previously was a Cyrillic spelling of the full name used which could've been cached somewhere and used in the message.
I don't think I've ever used this spelling in the profile itself, though.

Comment: In fact, I used that Google account to sign up and it probably had had that spelling back then.

Comment: Alerted the folks that produce these that there's an encoding issue.

Answer (score 36):

It seems that your name is a victim of a UTF-8 to latin1 [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake):

```
>>> 'Евгений'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
'Ð\x95Ð²Ð³ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ð¹'
```